# Connecting mobile phone to a computer localhost

Tags: android, macos, nginx, localhost

I'm developing a web application (I'm using MacOs) and I would like to see the screens on my android mobile device. Although both devices connected the same network I couldn't connect computer's IP address and local port on my phone. I'm thinking of this issue is showing up by MacOs. Because when I run same project in to Windows machine I can connect to the IP address with my phone. I've tried a couple of things but I couldn't solve the issue. What should I do be able to connect my phone to the computer's IP address ?

Comment: Is your application running in the port 8080? Check that the port is open otherwise it won't be able to receive connections

Comment: My application is running on http://localhost:4001. I'm using static_server.js file. I can see my application on my computer's web browser. But I couldn't access from my mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

Go check how can you create a server with a *"real world"* link using **ngrok** (https://ngrok.com).

Comment: In fact, I would like learn what causes that connection issue. I'm developing UI5 application and using static_server.js. I can run the project by typing node static_server.js. The application is running on http://localhost:4001

Comment: I'm developing Android app on MacOS and i know that every time i want to test a localhost server, i have to use ngrok, I honestly don't know other way around (excluding similar tools).

Answer (score 0):

I assume Nodejs application only bind to your local (MacOS) and only can access from your laptop. The option is using Nginx or Ngrok to open application to LAN or world.

If you want allow other devices from LAN to connect to your Mac, you can go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall then Off.